# Index out of range error when trying to access JSON data from structs

Tags: ios, json, swift, struct

I'm trying to get stock data from the IEX finance API and everything I need is outputting to the console just fine, but I'm having issues trying to then use that data to plug into my table view.

This the the [API url](https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=aapl,fb,msft,tsla,goog&types=quote,news,chart&range=1m&last=5), and this is the [JSON in a readable format](https://pastebin.com/UEWg8LH3).

These are the structs that I have set up

```
struct Welcome: Decodable {
    let aapl, fb, msft, tsla, goog: Aapl

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case aapl = "AAPL"
        case fb = "FB"
        case msft = "MSFT"
        case tsla = "TSLA"
        case goog = "GOOG"
    }
}

struct Aapl: Decodable {
    let quote: Quote
    let news: [News]
}

struct Quote: Decodable {
    let symbol: String
    let companyName: String
    let latestPrice: Double
}

struct News: Decodable {
    let url: String
    let image: String
}
```

This is how the data is fetched:

```
fetchData(url: stockApiUrl) { (result: FetchResult<Welcome>) -> (Void) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let object): self.stockData = [object]
        print("stockData: \n\n\(self.stockData)")
    case .failure(let error):
        print("Error decoding JSON: \n\n\(error)")
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And pass the data into

`var stockData = [Welcome]()`

With the code as it is now, it outputs all the data I need for the companies, but I'm confused as to how to access all the company data so I can grab each piece (`companyName`, `latestPrice`, etc) individually so I can display them in a table view.

For example in my `cellForRowAt` table view method I'm trying to set the `companyName` to labels, but using `let quotes = stockData[indexPath.row]` gives me an index out of range error, so I can't then use something like `cell.companyNameLabel = quotes[indexPath.row].companyName`.

I'm wondering if I need to restructure my structs (although I compared my code to the suggested code from quicktype.io and it's identical), or re-work something else.

Thanks for any guidance!

EDIT:

`numberOfRows` method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return stockData.count
    } else if section == 1 && fetchingMore {
        return 1
    }
    return 0
}
```

`fetchData` function:

```
func fetchData<T: Decodable>(url: URL, completion: @escaping (FetchResult<T>) -> (Void)) {

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data else {completion(.failure(error!)); return}

        do {
            //let object = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            let object = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String:Aapl].self,from: data)
            completion(.success(object))
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: You need to show your `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

Comment: I just edited my question to include that method - I actually had a set number in there but you reminded to to change that to `return stockData.count` instead. Now I don't get the index out of range error but it's only displaying one row, when the data call returns data for 5 companies so I'm not sure what's going on there. I still can't access the companyNames to put in the labels.

Comment: Unrelated to the out-of-range issue but consider that you are wrapping the result – which is the representation of a **dictionary** – in an array ( → `[object]`). This array contains necessarily only one item. I would write a custom initializer and convert the 5 stocks to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a more generic and descriptive name rename `Aapl` to `Stock`

```
struct Stock: Decodable {
    let quote: Quote
    let news: [News]
}
```

Declare `stockData` as dictionary and create an array for the keys

```
var stockData = [String:Stock]()
var keys = [String]()
```

Replace `fetchData` with

```
fetchData(url: stockApiUrl) { (result: FetchResult<[String:Stock]>) -> (Void) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let object): 
        self.stockData = object
        self.keys = Array(object.keys)
        print("stockData: \n\n\(self.stockData)")
    case .failure(let error):
        print("Error decoding JSON: \n\n\(error)")
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

In `cellForRow` write

```
let stock = stocks[keys[indexPath.row]]!
cell.companyNameLabel = stock.quote.companyName
```

Comment: isn't **keys[indexPath.row] = stocks.keys[indexPath.row]** ?? if yes why the new allocation

Comment: Yes, it is. But getting the keys over and over could be more expensive than using a static array.

Comment: This is a great solution, thanks vadian - I was hoping to find a solution that kept the generic `fetchData` function (that you also helped me out with!), so this is really perfect. I'll keep this approach in mind for future cases as well. Hope you have a great week, happy coding!

Comment: If I can ask a follow up question pertaining to this same issue (I can post a new question if necessary), how would I access the properties within my `[News]` struct with this approach? I've attempted `guard let webUrl = URL(string: stock.news[1].url) else {return}` in `didSelectRow` and when I print out `webUrl`, it prints all the `webUrl`s successfully, but they're all separate so I can't, for example, set `webView.load(URLRequest(url: webUrl))` or I'll get an index out of range crash. Thanks again for your patience and help vadian, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Comment: Absolutely, here's a link to the question if you have time to take a look, otherwise thank you so much for your help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53305031/accessing-properties-of-a-struct

Answer (score 1):

You may do

```
 var welcomes:[String:Aapl]!
```

---

```
 welcomes = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String:Aapl].self,from:jsonData)
```

then use this inside `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
return welcomes.keys.count
```

and inside `cellForRowAt`

```
let item = welcomes[welcomes.keys[indexPath.row]]!.quote.companyName
```

Use it if you don't care about sorting

Comment: Alright I gave this a shot.. if I change `let object = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)` to `let object = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String:Aapl].self,from: data)` within my `fetchData` function then try to change `numberOfRows` to `return object.keys.count`, I get the error `Use of unresolved identifier 'object'`

Comment: I edited my question to include the full `fetchData` function at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

This Problem mainly caused because you'r `DataSource` is something else .

for instance if you set `numberForRows in section` using `welcome.count` 
and used something else to iterate inside the `cellForRowAt` if that thing mismatch the number of `numberForRows` provided it will cause

> index out of range Error

Therefore make sure you're giving the same `DataSource` and iterate inside an array with the same range .

Now more into your case, i don't know how you set the `numberOfRows` but assuming is something else.

i would suggest the following.

instead of iterating the `quotes[indexPath.row]` instead use the same `DataSource` and work your way in, i assume its the `stockData` so assuming its like this on what your `structs` looks like

```
stockData[indexPath.row].qoutes.companyName
```

**UPDATE**

so for you'r problem the `JSON` it self too is not an `array` so doing some work around to make a final array of each `Aapl` is an option.

You can create one manually in `didSet` of `stockData` that returns you an array and use that instead to show data and iterate.

This code should give you an idea.

```
 var myFinalData: [Aapl] = [] {
    didSet {
        //reload your table
    }
}
var stockData = [Welcome]() {
    didSet{
        myFinalData.append(stockData.aapl)
        myFinalData.append(stockData.fb)
        // etc
    }
}
// then you can use myFinalData as you DataSource and iterate easily inside of it
```

Comment: this will work if your data source is stockData.count , if its something else it will throw same Error, so i hope you got the idea happy coding

Comment: Thanks, I had returned a set number of rows in numberOfRows but I've now changed it to return stockData.count - however even once doing that, I still can't set the labels to stockData[indexPath.row].quotes.companyName, as the only subscript members of `stockData[indexPath.row].` are the individual companies - i.e. I can set the labels to all display one company's name, but not all of them

Comment: its because your struct says exactly say ( aapl, fb, msft, tsla, goog) not an array of Aapl change your struct to have an array of Aapl and iterate from it do you need help in that ?

Comment: the response it self is not an array, so you can do some work around to wrap all of those objects into an array :)

Comment: If I change `Aapl` to `[Aapl]` in the `Welcome` struct I get the error: `typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "AAPL", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: this may destroy the company name  the quote belongs to

Comment: that is actually True @Sh_Khan thanks for the heads up and nice answer up there.

Comment: @Tobi trying this I get the error `Value of type '[StockTableViewController.Welcome]' has no member 'aapl'` on the line `myFinalData.append(stockData.aapl)`

Comment: @KingTim the other answer got it perfectly i guess,  altho hope i helped in something, and cleared something for you.