# Accessing properties of a [Struct]

Tags: swift, struct

I'm attempting to get certain pieces of JSON data to populate a table view, and I'm not sure how to access these properties without running into an index out of range error.

I'm getting the data from the IEX API ([JSON](https://pastebin.com/UEWg8LH3)):

```
    fetchData(url: stockApiUrl) { (result: FetchResult<[String:Stock]>) -> (Void) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let object):
            self.stockData = object
            self.keys = Array(object.keys)
        print("stockData: \n\n\(self.stockData)")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error decoding JSON: \n\n\(error)")
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

And using these structs to decode:

```
struct Welcome: Decodable {
    let aapl, fb, msft, tsla, goog: Stock

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case aapl = "AAPL"
        case fb = "FB"
        case msft = "MSFT"
        case tsla = "TSLA"
        case goog = "GOOG"
    }
}

struct Stock: Decodable {
    let quote: Quote
    let news: [News]
}

struct Quote: Decodable {
    let symbol: String
    let companyName: String
    let latestPrice: Double
}

struct News: Decodable {
    let url: String
    let image: String
}
```

The resulting data is set to a dictionary, and there's a `keys` variable so I can access to keys:

```
var stockData = [String:Stock]()
var keys = [String]()
```

Accessing the properties of `Stock` and `Quote` is ok, but I have an array of the `News` struct within `Stock`, and this is what's throwing me off. My goal is to use the `url` property of `News` in my `didSelectRow` method so I can use WebKit to load the company's `url` when a cell is tapped:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let stock = stockData[keys[indexPath.row]]!

    guard let webUrl = URL(string: stock.news[1].url) else {return}
    print("\n\n\nwebUrls:\n\n\n\n\n\(webUrl)\n\n\n\n")

    let webController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "webController") as! WebViewController

    webView.load(URLRequest(url: webUrl))
    webController.view = webView
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(webController, animated: true)
}
```

As you can see I've attempted accessing the properties with

```
guard let webUrl = URL(string: stock.news[1].url) else {return}
```

And printing `webUrl` successfully prints all of the urls, however they're all separate, as you can see here:

[image]

Because of this, `webView.load(URLRequest(url: webUrl)` is only getting one url (the first one) instead of all of them, resulting in the out of range error.

I'm wondering how I can change this to get all of the `url`s together instead of separate.

Comment: I don’t get the problem, you explicitly fetch a news object from the array: news[1].url why would you expect webUrl having multiple values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so basicly you struggle to iterate over an array if I understand it correct, here you are:

```
var urls = [String]()
stock.news.forEach { urls.append($0.url) }
print(urls)
```